# Laravel - Eloquent - temporarily disable touchOwners

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the model

> User

that performs a touchOwners on each record on saving.

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

  protected $touches = array('userDesk');

  [...]

}
```

The problem comes when I want to create a new record: eloquent try to do a touch on a field that does not exist in the related table (since the user has been newly created, then how can there be a record which refers to this user in the related table?!?...).

How do I temporarily disable this function in order to allow me to create a new user without incurring in the exception:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Collection
>   :: touchOwners ()

?

I tried with this:

```
$user->setTouchedRelations(array());
```

but of course it did not work...

Comment: what do you mean by `of course it did not work`? It is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a model without `touching` pass `false` to `save` method:

```
$someModel = new SomeModel;
... // do something with your model

$someModel->save(['touch' => false]);
```

Of course `setTouchedRelations` will work as well:

```
$someModel = new SomeModel;
... // do what you need

$someModel->setTouchedRelations([]);
$someModel->save();
```